# Iterate recursive function

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I know for this need use recursive function.
Need help to transform this object

```
{ '1': {},
  '2': {
         '3': {},
         '4': { '6': {}, '7': {} },
         '5': { '8': {}, '9': {} } 
  }
}
```

to this array of objects

```
[
  { key: 1 },
  { 
    key: 2,
    children: [
                {key: 3},
                {
                  key: 4,
                  children: [{key: 6}, {key: 7}],
                },
                {
                  key: 5,
                  children: [{key: 8}, {key: 9}],
                }
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing a **specific** problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create recursive function using `reduce()` method.

```js
var obj = {"1":{},"2":{"3":{},"4":{"6":{},"7":{}},"5":{"8":{},"9":{}}}}

function f(data) {
  return Object.keys(data).reduce((r, k) => {
    let o = {key: k}
    if (Object.keys(data[k]).length) o.children = f(data[k]);
    r.push(o)
    return r;
  }, [])
}

let result = f(obj)
console.log(result)
```